# How important is triangle inequality for statistical estimators?

Tags: correlation, distance, estimators, metric, inequality

(Pearson's) correlation is a measure of co-dependence that does not fulfill certain axioms such non-negativity and triangle inequality. In layman's terms, how would you describe what triangle inequality is?

Given that correlation is in widespread use, does this mean that triangle inequality is not important for statistical measures in general, and can be bypassed when using these estimators? Why then is triangle inequality more important for distance metrics, more commmonly used in clustering? What is the intuition for it being at all important?

What are alternatives that do fulfill triangle inequality and why aren't they more popular?

Comment: Why are you trying to think of correlation as a metric? It measures strength (and direction) of linear association association - not the interaction between variables.

Comment: thanks, I've now edited the question knowing that correlation is not a metric

Comment: Although $\rho$ is not a metric (for data), it is readily transformed (via the inverse cosine) to a metric (on the manifold of centered, standardized vectors: that is, a *sphere*).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Angular_distance_and_similarity.